# OO PHP Accessing public variable from another class

Tags: php, oop

I have a class like the following:

```
class game {

    public $db;
    public $check;
    public $lang;

    public function __construct() {

        $this->check = new check();

        $this->lang = DEFAULT_LANG;
        if (isset($_GET['lang']) && !$this->check->isEmpty($_GET['lang']))
            $this->lang = $_GET['lang'];
    }

}
```

As you can see I have a public variable `$lang` that is also defined via the contructor.

The proble is that I want to access the result of this variable from other classes that are not directly related to this class, since I don't want to redeclare it for each different class.

So for example how can I call the result of that variable from another class, lets call it `class Check` ?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

if you mark the `public $lang;` as static:

```
public static $lang;
```

you can access it via `game::$lang;`

if not static, you need to make an instance of game and directly access it:

```
$game = new game;
$game->lang;
```

static call inside of (current) class:

```
self::$lang;
```

[late static bound](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) call (to inherited static variable):

```
static::$lang;
```

call from child class to parent:

```
parent::$lang;
```

normal call inside of an instance (instance is when you use `new Obj();`):

```
$this->lang;
```

**BTW:**
variables defined by `define('DEFAULT_LANG', 'en_EN');` are GLOBAL scope, mean, can access everywhere!

```
<?php
define('TEST', 'xxx');

class game {
    public function __construct() {
        echo TEST;
    }
}

//prints 'xxx'
new game;
```

Answer (score 5):

you can make it static variable, so you will be able to call it anytime anywhere, the diff is that instead of

```
$this->lang;
```

when editing it(Works inside class game only) you do :

```
self::$lang;
```

and when you call/edit it (Works everywhere) from anther class you do :

```
game::$lang
```

the idea of static class is that its exist only in one instance, so only one $lang exist in your program. but there is no need to load the whole class to get acsess to it.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I call the result of that variable from another class, lets call it class Check?

A variable doesn't have a *result*. If you mean to retrieve the state of that variable on a specific object `$obj` of class `game` then you can simply do:

```
$obj->lang
```

On a side note if `$lang` is publicly only read only you should protect it by defining it `private` or `protected` and create a *getter method* instead.

If you mean that you want to use the same variable name in another class I'd suggest you to consider *inheritance*:

```
class Check extends game { /* now Check has $lang */ }
```

but the variable of the two objects will be different.

Answer (score 0):

Since the property is public, you can access it from outside the class as `$objInstance->property`. It doesn't matter if you're calling it from a function, procedural script, in another object. As long as you have the instance, you can call it's public property. Ex:

```
function foo($c) {
    echo $c->lang;
}
foo($check);
```

Also, some advice on working with objects and such: It's considered better code if you don't create instances of objects in the other objects, but rather pass them in someway (either a setter method or through the constructor). This keeps the classes loosely coupled and results in code that is more reusable and easier to test. So:

```
class Game
{

...
public function __construct($check, $defaultLang, $get) {

    $this->check = $check;

    $this->lang = $defaultLang;
    if (isset($get['lang']) && !$this->check->isEmpty($get['lang']))
        $this->lang = $get['lang'];
}
...

$game = new Game(new Check(), DEFAULT_LANG, $_GET);
echo $game->check;
```

The first half of [this article](http://phpmaster.com/dependency-injection-with-pimple/) is an accessible explanation of what is known as Dependency Injection.

Comment: As I said I want to call it within another class, not externally in a procedural code or in a simple function