# Difference between static:: and $this::

Tags: php, static, this, self

I know there is a difference between `static::` and `self::` like in this example ( from https://stackoverflow.com/a/13613718/2342518 )

```
<?php
class One
{
    const TEST = "test1";
    function test() { echo static::TEST; }
}
class Two extends One
{
    const TEST = "test2";
}

$c = new Two();
$c->test();
```

Which returns *test2* when `static::TEST` is used and *test1* when `self::TEST` is used.
But it also returns *test2* when `$this::TEST` is used.

**`static::TEST` can be used inside a static method, whereas `$this::TEST` requires an instance before being used (so non-usable in static methods).**

But if one cannot use `$this::` in static methods, `static::` can be used in non-static methods (like in the example).

So, **what is the difference between static:: and $this:: in a non static method?**

---

*Optional complete test*

```
<?php
abstract class AOne
{
    const TEST = "test1";
    abstract public function test();
}
class OneStatic extends AOne
{
    public function test()
    {
        return static::TEST;
    }
}
class TwoStatic extends OneStatic
{
    const TEST = "test2";
}
class OneSelf extends AOne
{
    public function test()
    {
        return self::TEST;
    }
}
class TwoSelf extends OneSelf
{
    const TEST = "test2";
}
class OneThis extends AOne
{
    public function test()
    {
        return $this::TEST;
    }
}
class TwoThis extends OneThis
{
    const TEST = "test2";
}

$objects = array(
    'one, static::'     => new OneStatic(),
    'two, static::'     => new TwoStatic(),
    'one,   self::'     => new OneSelf(),
    'two,   self::'     => new TwoSelf(),
    'one,  $this::'     => new OneThis(),
    'two,  $this::'     => new TwoThis(),
);

$results = array();
foreach ($objects as $name=>$object)
    $results[$name] = $object->test();

var_dump($results);
?>
```

Which yields

- 'one, static::' => 'test1'
- 'two, static::' => 'test2'
- 'one,   self::' => 'test1'
- 'two,   self::' => 'test1'
- 'one,  $this::' => 'test1'
- 'two,  $this::' => 'test2'

So self refers to the class where the method is defined, but there's no difference between `$this::` and `static::` in these non static methods.

Comment: Your last conclusion is indeed correct :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [OO PHP Accessing public variable from another class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17576843/oo-php-accessing-public-variable-from-another-class)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are three cases when you **CAN'T** use `$this::` over `static::`

**1. In static methods**

```
public static function test() {
    return $this::MY_CONST;
}
```

**Output:**

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context

**2. In none-static methods which get called from a non-object context**

```
class A {
    const MY_CONST = 33;
    public function test() {
        return $this::MY_CONST;
    }
}

echo A::test(); // test method here is called without instantiating class A
```

**Output:**

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context

### Updates:

As of PHP 8 calling a non-static method from a non-object context is not allowed and will yield the following error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Non-static method A::test() cannot be called statically

**3. When using the special `::class` keyword**

```
class A {
    public function test() {
        return $this::class;
    }
}

$a = new A;
echo $a->test();
```

**Output:**

> Fatal error:  Dynamic class names are not allowed in compile-time

***Note: in all the three cases `static::` will work***

---

For the last case
[PHP Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class) states that:

> **Note:**
>
> The class name resolution using ::class is a compile time
> transformation. That means at the time the class name string is
> created no autoloading has happened yet. As a consequence, class names
> are expanded even if the class does not exist. No error is issued in
> that case.

***So you can't use `$this::class` because you can't reference to non-existent classes***

### PHP 8

The behavior in PHP 8 has changed!

For consistency reasons `$this::class` now provides the same result as `get_class($this)` and `static::class`

https://3v4l.org/iB99O

Comment: I indeed forgot about the `$this::class` which is a good example, as others are actually based off static methods (or "called-like-static", ie anywhere `$this` doesn't exist)

Answer (score 5):

There really isn't one. The `::` functionality has been expanded over time, so that the left hand side doesn't need to be a class literal but may also be an object instance or string variable with a class name. Sometime around the same time late static binding was introduced with the `static` keyword. As you said, `$this` can't be used in static methods, so `static` is the obvious and only choice here for late static binding.

In an object instance however you could use `static::` to refer to the late-static bound class, which will be the class of the current object instance. Or you could use `$this::` as a side effect of being able to use an object instance as shorthand for `<class of this object $var>::`. The end result is the same, it's simply functionality which happens to overlap in this particular point. The internal workings are somewhat different, but I can't think of a case where there would ever be any difference.

Just to complete the Venn diagram:

Only `static` can do this:

```
public static function foo() {
    static::FOO;
}
```

Only `$var::` can do this:

```
$obj = new Foo;
$obj::FOO;
```

Both can do this:

```
public function foo() {
    static::FOO;
    $this::FOO;
}
```