# Referring to a constant in PHP 7 using static::MY_CONST vs self::MY_CONST vs SomeClass::MY_CONST

Tags: php, php-7

I would like to make it clear once and for all.

I'm pretty sure I know when to use `self::MY_CONST` and `SomeClass::MY_CONST` but it's unclear when to use `static::MY_CONST`.

> You use self::MY_CONST…

…when you refer to a constant **that is defined in the same class where you call it**.

Example:

```
class Foo 
{
    const MY_CONST = 123;

    public function example() 
    {
        echo self::MY_CONST;
    }
}
```

> You use AnotherClass::MY_CONST…

…when you refer to a constant **that is defined in different class that the one from where you call it**.

Example:

```
class Bar
{
    const MY_CONST = 123;
}

class Foo 
{
    public function example() 
    {
        echo Bar::MY_CONST;
    }
}
```

> You use static::MY_CONST…

…when? I don't know. In terms of referring constants using `static` makes no sense to me. Please provide a valid reason or confirm that `self::` and `SomeClass::` examples are sufficient.

**edit: My question is not a duplicate.** I don't ask about `$this` at all. Don't mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between static:: and $this::](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24476194/difference-between-static-and-this)

Comment: Hi @PierreDuc, I don't think this is a duplicate. I have a clear question that has nothing to do with `$this`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exactly are late static bindings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912902/what-exactly-are-late-static-bindings-in-php)

Comment: @slick: It is a duplicate, but not of the one selected by PierreDuc. There are [many other questions about late static binding](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+late+static+binding), though. Which you might have found doing some research.

Comment: I think @IMSoP gave a nice example where I can see some difference. My conclusion is that if I operate only within a class with no inheritance I can keep using `self::` otherwise `static::` would be a way to go, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `static` keyword is needed for something called "Late Static Binding" (see also [What exactly are late static bindings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912902/what-exactly-are-late-static-bindings-in-php)). The [manual page on that topic](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) is not the clearest, but this sentence is key:

> "Late binding" comes from the fact that static:: will not be resolved using the class where the method is defined but it will rather be computed using runtime information.

Effectively, `static::` is similar to `$this`, in that it resolves to the class where the code is *running*, which might be a sub-class of the class where the code is *written*.

Let's use your example of `self::`, and add a sub-class:

```
class Foo 
{
    const MY_CONST = 123;

    public function example() 
    {
        echo self::MY_CONST;
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo
{
    const MY_CONST = 456;
}

$bar = new Bar;
$bar->example();
```

This will output `123`, because the `self::` in the definition always refers to `Foo`, regardless of how you call it.

However, if we change to use late static binding:

```
class Foo 
{
    const MY_CONST = 123;

    public function example() 
    {
        echo static::MY_CONST;
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo
{
    const MY_CONST = 456;
}

$bar = new Bar;
$bar->example();
```

Now it will echo `456`, because the `static::` resolves to the class we were actually using at runtime when we made the call, which was `Bar`, and `Bar::MY_CONST` has a different value.

Comment: Wow, it's clearer now. So basically it looks like using `static` is a way to go when you have inheritance, but when you operate only within a single class, the `self` is sufficient, right?

Answer (score 0):

This example will show you all the difference:

```
<?php

class A
{
    const TEST = 'A';

    static function echoSelf()
    {
        echo self::TEST . PHP_EOL;
    }

    static function echoStatic()
    {
        echo static::TEST . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    const TEST = 'B';
}

echo 'Using self:' .PHP_EOL;
A::echoSelf(); // A
B::echoSelf(); // A

echo 'Using static:' .PHP_EOL;
A::echoStatic(); // A
B::echoStatic(); // B
```

Enjoy ;)