# How to get access to a variable form another class?

Tags: php

I'm doing form validation and I have a little problem. In the Insert class, I want to insert into the database the data that should be entered in the user form. Before adding the data to the database, I check the $ errors variable for errors. if it doesn't, I add it, and if it doesn't, I don't add Only that the $ errors variable is in the Validation class. And here is my question, what should I do to use the $ errors variable from the UserValidation class in the Insert class. I will add that I am using dependency injection. I would be grateful for the tips.

```js
class Insert
{

 private $data;
 private $database;
 private $validation;

    public function __construct($data, $database, $validation)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->database = $database;
        $this->validation = $validation;
    }

    public function hash_password()
    {
        $field = $this->data['password'];
        return $hash = password_hash($field, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    }

    public function insert_user()
    {
        $login = $this->data['login'];
        $password = $this->data['password'];
        $hash = $this->hash_password();
        
        
        if(empty($this->errors))
        {
            $sql = $this->database->connect()->prepare("INSERT INTO users(`login`, `password`) VALUES(:login, :password)");
            $sql->bindParam(':login', $login, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $sql->bindParam(':password',$hash, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $sql->execute();
            
        }
        
    }

    }   
}



?>
```

```js
class UserValidation
{
    private $data;
    private $errors = '';
    private $database;
    
    public function __construct($data, $database)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->database = $database;
    }
    
    
    public function validateLogin()
    {
        $val = $this->data['login'];
        
        if(empty($val))
        {
            return $this->errors = "Field can not empty";
        }
        else if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z-0-9]{4,12}$/', $val))
        {
        return $this->errors = "Login have to get from 4 to 12 chars.";
        }else
        {
            $sql = $this->database->connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM users where login = :login");
            $sql->bindParam(':login', $val, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $sql->execute();        

             if($sql->rowCount())
             {
                 return $this->errors = "Login is exist;
             }
        }
            
    }
    
    public function validatePassword()
    {
        $val = trim($this->data['password']);
        
        if(empty($val))
        {
            return $this->errors = 'Field can not empty';
        }
        else if(!empty($val) && !preg_match('/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]{5,31}$/', $val))
        {
            return $this->errors =' Password have to get almost 6 chars and begin from letter';
        }
    }
```

Comment: tried setting it as global $var? https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Does it answers your question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17576843/oo-php-accessing-public-variable-from-another-class/17577012